# How to disable PostBack in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, postback

When the page loads Dropdown is set to "SELECT". If the Start All button is clicked then the Dropdown text is now set to "Start" but its doing PostBack. How can I change the Dropdown text on the fly without any postback. Therefore when a user clicks on the Start All button the Dropdown text is set to Start without using PostBack.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function buttonFunction() {
        ddlAction();
    }
    function ddlAction() {
        var ddl = document.getElementById('<%=DropDownList1.ClientID %>');
        var selectedvalue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value = "1";
        var selectedtext = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex.value["1"]].text;
    }
</script>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownList1"
            onChange="ddlAction();">
            <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="SELECT" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Start" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Stop" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <br />
        <button id="btnID" onclick="buttonFunction()">Start All</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You really want to think about disabling postback, postback in webforms is pretty fundamental. That's why almost everyone has moved onto MVC now and abandoned web forms. So this change is very non-trivial. You'll have all kinds of trouble synchronising Viewstate without postback.

Comment: You haven't defined a "type" for you button so it is behaving like a submit button. Add `type="button"`

Comment: Even doing that won't change the DDL @Turnip. It'll stop it posting back, but now the select won't work properly as the value set by Js won't be reflected in the Viewstate

Comment: onclick="buttonFunction();return false"

Comment: @Liam The viewstate doesn't really matter if OP is only wanting to run some JS without a postback.

Comment: In which case why is it a `asp:DropDownList`? I'm guessing the OP isn't going to clarify.... <sigh>

Comment: I'm controlling services in on servers. If a user clicks the Start All button I just want to set the dropdown to Start. Therefore if there's one service that you dont want to start you can just leave change it to Select.